# Alternative of Cassandra for storing User data with high IO

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

We are looking for a technology stack which will have the following criteria.

1. We will be having around 10 million customer.
2. Each customer will be having around 20MB+ of data.
3. Data of each user will be updated everyday.
4. We need to store the data for more than six months.
5. We may need to query on the data any time within the time span of six months.

Currently we are thinking to use Cassandra, but the limitation of maximum storage per node in Cassandra should be less than 3TB, we are looking for other alternatives to use with or without Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if my suggestion applies for your case. We had a similar case with one of our products. There was created a blob field to record binary data, as pdf documents, that made the database grew considerably.
The solution we made was to create a second database, as a repository for records older then one year. At the application server there's a service running which:
1) Copies the records, from specific tables, older then one year to this second database;
2) Deletes records from the main database, once we have a copy in the other side;
3) Queries that need data older then one year are directed to this second database;

Sure, we had to do some implementations on the code to adapt to this situation, but is running good so far.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we will be querying on the data which are in below one year range, and the processing of the data less than one year will be done everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ScyllaDB. It's a C++ reimplementation of Cassandra at 10x the speed. Scylla supports 10TB/node and there are examples of larger amounts per node. Proper disclosure - I work there but am speaking from experience.

You can definitely consider just to store the metadata itself in the database and the blobs on a separate nodes outside but it's complex and Scylla can store it all altogether. Such a similar system is already in production and we hope that user will eventually open source it